# Show $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq M\subseteq N$ where both $M$ and $N$ are splitting fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be the splitting field of $x^{10}-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $N$ be the splitting field of $x^{10}-100$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq M\subseteq N$ and find $[N:\mathbb{Q}]$. I know that $M$ is also the splitting field of $x^5-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $[M:\mathbb{Q}]=4.$ But what should I do with this?

Comment: What's the splitting number for the field of N over M? Then N over Q is N over M times M over Q, gives you the result, does it not?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. I need to show the inclusion relation is true and $N$ is an extension of $M$. But I have no idea.

Comment: Does the difference of two squares help at all? $x^5-1$ divides $x^{10}-1$.

Comment: @Nij I didn't see how this can help me. How can I use that to show the inclusion relation?

Comment: Hint: If $M_1$ is the splitting field of $x^{10}-1$ over $\mathbb Q$, then $M_1=\mathbb Q(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a primitive 10th root of unity. If $N_1$ is the splitting field of $x^{10}-100$ over $\mathbb Q$, then $N_1=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[10]{100}\;\omega)$.

Comment: It's enough to show $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]{100},\omega)$, right? Also, what is $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]{100},\omega):\mathbb{Q}]$?

Comment: @GeorgeLaw: you mean $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[10]{100},\omega)$, not $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[10]{100}\omega)$.

Comment: @Kelan: you need to show that $x^{10}-1$ splits completely in $N$. Can you write any root of $x^{10}-1$ as a quotient of roots of $x^{10}-100$, for example?

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry, typo.

Comment: @Kelan $\sqrt[10]{100}\;\omega$.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Is $\sqrt[10]{100}\omega$ an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]{100},\omega)$? I don't think it is, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]{100},\omega)=\{a+b\sqrt[10]{100}+c\omega, a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin What about $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]{100},\omega):\mathbb{Q}]$, I guess it's 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that

$$x^{10}-100=(x^5-10)(x^5+10)$$

Now,  over the rationals the splitting field of $\;x^{10}-1\;$ is $\;M:=\Bbb Q(\omega)\;,\;\;\omega:=e^{\pi i/5}\;$, whereas the splitting field of $\;x^{10}-100\;$ is $\;N:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{10},\,\omega)\;$ (be sure you can prove this), so we can see that both

$$M\le N\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;[N:M]=5$$

since the minimal polynomial of $\;\sqrt[5]{10}\;$ over $\;M\;$ is $\;x^5-10\;$ .